# System.NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, abp

I downloaded one abp .net core2.x angular solution and try to implement report using Devexpress reporting control. So I added the corresponding packages to the project. While running the projects its show that internal server error, I checked the log and found that System.NotSupportedException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.QueryBuilder.QueryBuilderController.Invoke (DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting.v19.1). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0

I tried to modify the DocInclusionPredicate. but it will not solve the issue.
I tried to modify like below,

```
            options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) =>
            {
                var assemblyName = ((ControllerActionDescriptor)description.ActionDescriptor).ControllerTypeInfo.Assembly.GetName().Name;
                var currentAssemblyName = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
                return currentAssemblyName == assemblyName;
            });
```

To reproduce the issue, Add DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting package to the Web.Host project and run that.

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe a version rolling forward issue?! Against which runtime is your application developed and which SDK do you run on the server?

Comment: I am using .net core 2.2 , visual studio 2019 and Devexpress v19.1